# Google Places API Limits

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am looking into the [Google Places Autocompleter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#adding_autocomplete). It works perfectly, I tried using the code provided.

However I see they mention something about limits per API key. First of all, I don't have an API key, and it works. I dont see a limit regarding no API keys?

Secondly, do they limit per client IP (the browser that is viewing my site), per domain, or something else?

If they limit per domain, will sub1.domain.com and sub2.domain.com share the same limit?

I can't seem to find anything regarding this in the Google documentation, which is why I am asking here. Thanks!

Edit: So I signed up for an API key, but they dont tell me where to include it to use the Places Autocomplete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as the key is concerned, it's only required for the Places web service: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/

Your doc link is to the Places library - that's a service of the JavaScript API v3. A key isn't required there, though you can include one by adding `&key={yourkey}` when you load the Maps JS (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HelloWorld).

So:

- Places web service: key required
- Places JavaScript service: no key required

I don't know about specific autocomplete limits, but the JS API has limits mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage. Basically, 25,000 map loads per day, with the option to purchase more if required.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am also using the autocomplete feature and need information on the limit. I have the api key in my call but I don't see any usage in the Google console report. The documentations says a request is counted if there is a map load and since I am just using the autocomplete am I ok with the limit?

Answer (score 7):

The Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Places Library does not require an API key to implement and does not have a documented limit. However, if a user performs more queries than deemed acceptable by Google in one minute, they will receive the `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` status in response to a request.