# Google Places Autocomplete API Consumption

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm using google maps API on my company, and we're facing some issues with the consumption of the API.

We use the Javascript API, loading the map, and we geocode some address and make some routes. Everything normal.

But we use the Autocomplete in some cases, to allow the user to input the location he's searching.

So, I define the autocomplete like this:

> var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
>         document.getElementById('textBox'),
>         { types: [] });

When the user select an option, we call the function

> autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', doSomething);

get the place and do more things

> function doSomething() { var place =
>   autocomplete.getPlace();
>
> //more code }

Everything works fine, but when the user start typing, it's been consuming the Google Places API Web Service. Is it right?

I thought it would only consume the Javascript API when we loads the map, and that's it.

And the weird thing is that, on the developer's console, the utilization of the API started few days ago (30/06/2016), and we have a gap of no utilization of this API (between 3th and 10th of July), and yesterday we reach the limit of 1000 uses.

Am I doing something wrong? What can I do?

Sorry if this is not the right place for the question, and if it's not, move it or tell me so I can open in the new place.

Thanks

Comment: In addition, I'm using the same API KEY for the development environment and for two distinct servers in production.

Only in one server the usage of API is counting. The other one, and the developer environment I can use and it doesn't count at the usage

Comment: I think this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922800/google-places-api-limits) can give you an idea, especially the part that JavaScript API doesn't need any key to work. So it cannot consume any usage. To know more about the usage and limits of Places API, visit this [link](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage). You can also check this [pros and cons of Places API](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-each-Places-API).

Answer (score 0):

You can find an answer in this blog post:

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html

Look at 4. Starting from June 22, 2016 Google counts client-side requests against the corresponding web service APIs. Apparently, some of your domains were "grandfathered", but the new ones will follow the new policy.